# How to wait for beforeEach to execute before continuing with the flow in describe?

Tags: typescript, async-await, mocha.js

I have the following TypeScript files:

**foo.ts**

```
import { shouldBehaveLikeBar } from "./bar";

describe("Foo", function() {
  const wallets: Wallet[];

  beforeEach(async function() {
    wallets = (await ethers.getSigners()) as Wallet[];
  });

  shouldBehaveLikeBar(wallets);
});
```

**bar.ts**

```
export function shouldBehaveLikeBar(wallets: Wallet[]) {
  describe("Bar", function() {
    it("should test something", async function() {
      const something = await callFunctionThatNeeds(wallets[0].address);
      expect(something).to.equal(true);
    });
  });
}
```

Basically, I need `wallets[0]` to exist in the `should test something` test suite. But it doesn't, I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

I thought that mocha would wait for `beforeEach` to execute before passing the values onto `shouldBehaveLikeBar`. How can I do this?

Comment: This is exactly *why* XSpec test frameworks use callbacks to describe/it/beforeEach/etc.- it delays execution, initially you're just *registering* code to be executed later on. `beforeEach` will be executed before other `it` or `describe` *callbacks* registered inside `describe("Foo"`'s callback, but `shouldBehaveLikeBar` is being called at registration time and therefore closes over the initial `undefined` value of `wallets`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for your input. In spite of my lack of understanding of how xSpec test frameworks handle callbacks, I don't see why the question should be closed - it's likely that I'm not the first and I won't be the last to make this mistake and look for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to achieve what I want. It involves using the [delayed root suite](https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite) functionality.

This is how the `foo.ts` file should be rewritten:

```
import { shouldBehaveLikeBar } from "./bar";

setTimeout(async function() {
  const wallets: Wallet[] = (await ethers.getSigners()) as Wallet[];

  describe("Foo", function() {
    shouldBehaveLikeBar(wallets);
  });

  run();
}, 1000);
```

Also a side note: make sure that you have the [@types/mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mocha) package installed, so the TypeScript compiler can infer the provenience of the `run` function.