# How to add types to "this" keyword in mocha tests?

Tags: typescript, types, mocha.js, this

I'm initialing some async data in my mocha tests using the [delayed root suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62175028/how-to-wait-for-beforeeach-to-execute-before-continuing-with-the-flow-in-describ) functionality.

In my top-most `beforeEach`, I'm creating some objects with specific types and store them in the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) object. In the child test files in the `it` suites, I'm using `this` to avoid duplicating the code countless times, but I'm losing the typings by doing so:

```
it("should do something", async function() {
  await this.token.approve(account, amount);
});
```

To get back them back (particularly the auto-complete functionality), I have to add an additional line of code:

```
const token: Erc20 = this.token;
await token.approve(account, amount);
```

I know that I could do this inline by casting with parentheses, yet I'd prefer to not do that.

Is there any way to define the typings for the "this" owner object of all test suite functions?

Comment: I think standard practice in TypeScript is to use lexical scoping, e.g. https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2245#issuecomment-218321301 .

Comment: You can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to extend Mocha's `this` type. But that will declare the property for *all* Mocha tests, not just the ones in that file.

Comment: With lexical scoping, I'd have to pass a bajillion variables via function parameters. Furthermore, as GitHub user iknowcss 
rambles in his [comment](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2245#issuecomment-523840745), this solution has other downsides as well.

Comment: Ah, by "lexical scoping" I mean declaring a variable in the enclosing scope and assigning to / reading from that. Which is what iknowcss supports as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend Mocha's `Context` interface and declare your additional test-context properties.

```
interface MyContext extends Mocha.Context {
  token: Erc20;
}
```

In your test functions, you can add type information for `this` parameter as follows:

```
it('should do something', async function(this: MyContext) {
  await this.token.approve();
});
```

**UPDATE**

The code above does not compile in `strict` mode (`error TS2769: No overload matches this call.`) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62283449/69868 for an alternative solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: `No overload matches this call... Type "Context" is not assignable to type "MyContext"`. Do I have to specify a new context type in some mocha configuration?

Comment: The reason for this seems to be that Mocha expects the functions passed to `before`, `beforeEach`, `it`, etc., to have a `Context` type. It doesn't accept descendant types. [Link to the source code](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bf720a41e4a4fcd9375e7ea545db191b8bea9184/types/mocha/index.d.ts#L2216-L2224).

Comment: I ended up accepting this answer, because it fittingly tackles the "this" keyword issue, and [I posted another question for this type inheritance puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62282408/how-to-extend-mochas-context-interface).

Comment: Weird. I created a small TypeScript file and it compiled fine in non-strict mode. I was able to reproduce the compilation problem after enabling `strict` mode.