# How to extend Mocha's Context interface?

Tags: typescript, types, mocha.js

Take the following code snippet:

```
import { Foo } from "./foo";

export interface MyContext extends Mocha.Context {
  foo: Foo;
}
```

This is in a project with the [@types/mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mocha) package installed, so that the `Mocha` namespace can be inferred by the compiler.

Now, if I try to use this interface in a test suite:

```
import { MyContxt } from "../types/mocha";

describe("my test suite", function() {
  it("should do something", function(this: MyContext) {
    ...
  });
});
```

The TypeScript compiler throws the following error:

> No overload matches this call.

I looked up the [source code](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bf720a41e4a4fcd9375e7ea545db191b8bea9184/types/mocha/index.d.ts#L2216-L2224), and it seems that mocha expects any function passed to the `before`, `beforeEach`, `it`, etc., hooks to be linked to a `Context` type as defined in `@types/mocha` - it doesn't accept any descendant types.

How can I go around this and extend the Mocha Context interface in my testing environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Literally extending mocha's `Context` type using that derived interface is not what you want to do here. Instead, you want to augment the type defined by the library, adding your member.

This can be accomplished as follows:

```
// augmentations.d.ts
import {Foo} from './foo';

declare module "mocha" {
  export interface Context {
    foo: Foo;
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
describe("my test suite", function () {
  it("should do something", function () {
    console.log(this.foo);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But now I if type `this` in any of my test suites, I get no auto-complete, so I don't think my local compiler is aware of these augmentations. I placed them in a file that is included via a glob pattern under the `include` property of `tsconfig.json`. If this is incorrect, how should I tell TypeScript about my changes to the Mocha namespace?

Comment: I fiddled with different implementations, but none worked. I ended up posting a question for this puzzle: [How to augment @types/mocha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289629/how-to-augment-types-mocha).

Comment: I'll take a look. You don't need to mention the file at all actually.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg, I had a silly mistake. It is now fixed.

Comment: Thanks, Aluan! This worked. I could swear that I tried removing the namespace yesterday, and it didn't work, but it does now!