# How to augment @types/mocha?

Tags: typescript, types, mocha.js, module-augmentation

I tried to apply Aluan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62283449/3873510) in countless different ways, but none worked, that is, none gave me the sweet auto-complete for the types that I augmented:

### augmentations.d.ts

```
import { Foo } from './foo';

declare module "mocha" {
  namespace Mocha {
    export interface Context {
      foo: Foo;
    }
  }
}
```

I made sure that the `augmentations.d.ts` file is part of a glob pattern in the `include` property of `tsconfig.json`, but this is all I see in VSCode when I type `this` in a test hook:

[image: Mocha this autocomplete]

Specifically mentioning `this` as the argument for the `it` hook didn't work either:

```
it("should do something", async function (this: Mocha.Context) {
 ...
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my answer.

Comment: Probably close this

Comment: I answered the question myself. I think it's helpful to keep both open, since the issues are somewhat different and many others will probably encounter them too.

Comment: The question seems exactly the same. The reason to close is that it is exactly so that others encountering it won't have to jump back and fourth between largely identical questions and their comments. Duplicate questions make SO harder to use, not easier

Comment: If you want to help people that might make the same error that I made in my answer, that could be worthwhile except that you don't explain why my answer _was_ incorrect, when it would be correct, etc.

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was eventually provided by Aluan. There was a minor typo in his original answer.

Just remove the namespace:

```
import { Foo } from './foo';

declare module "mocha" {
  export interface Context {
    foo: Foo;
  }
}
```